# In Octopress, how to create a folder similar as blog folder and list archives files?

Tags: octopress

I use Octopress write my blog.

I like write some notes, and don't want publish them as blog.
So I create a fold named `note` in `source` folder, and put some markdown file in it. [see source code structure](https://github.com/fancyoung/fancyoung.github.com/tree/source/source)

It works, but I don't know how to list all note archives' title and link in one page. Now I list them manually, [see code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fancyoung/fancyoung.github.com/source/source/note/index.md).

My questions are:
Is my solution (create a new folder) the best way ?
How to write code list files instead of update manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use [jekyll collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).

In your _config.yml, add :

```
collections:
  notes:
    output: true
```

Rename your `note` folder to `_notes`

And you can now list all your notes with :

```
<ul>
{% for note in site.notes %}
  <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{ note.url }}">{{ note.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works !  (PS: If it not works, update Octopress to new version)